# Hide/Show TextBox issue using JQuery

Tags: jquery, textbox

i am displaying a textbox(Suppose A) when there is a focus on textbox(Suppose B) and hiding when focus is out.it is working well.I want to enter something in Box A,but it gets hide when focus is out from B.Here i want like this.
if something is typed in B,A should not hide even focus is then out from B.
This is my jQuery code.

```
 $('#lastname').focusin(function () {
        $('input.hidden').fadeIn(1000);
        $('input.hidden').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
        }).focusout(function () {
        $('input.hidden').hide();
        });
```

This is Html Code.

```
 <table>
     <tr>
    <td>
   <label>First Name</label></td>
   <td> <input class="required" type="text" name="firstname"    id="firstname" /><span>(required)</span></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td><br/><label for="lastname">Last Name</label></td>

    <td><input class="required" type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname"/><span>(required)</span></td>
     <%-- 
    <td><br/><label>Invisible</label></td>--%>

    <td><input class="hidden" type="text" name="invisible"  value="Middle Name" id="invisible"/><span>(required)</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><br/><label>Address</label></td>
    <td><input class="required" type="text" name="address" id="address"/><span>(required)</span></td>
    </tr>
     </table>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Done.You can check updated Question.

Answer (score 0):

Check that the B contains some value if no than execute the hide code as like below

```
$('#lastname').focusin(function () {
   $('input.hidden').fadeIn(1000);
    $('input.hidden').css('backgroundColor', 'yellow');
}).focusout(function () {
    if(this.value.length <= 0)
       $('input.hidden').hide();
});
```